# SignalR error on server, not on dev machine

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, signalr

What i'm trying to achieve is to make a little multiplayer game for the new year and using (to learn) SignalR as communication method. On my development machine (windows 7, iis 7.5, asp.net forms 4.0 integrated) everything goes correct. The transport method with SignalR is **serverSentEvents** and when I let player 2 join it's working nicely

Still if I deploy my website on a server (windows server 2008, iis 7.0, asp.net 4.0 integrated) nothing works as expected. SignalR is loaded and I see a lot requests like the negotiate and after that the connect. Still no correct communication is done when I connect player 2 and the transport method also differs; as I read from the FireBug net view it tells me it's **longPolling**

If you would like to take a look, visit; http://ny.scsterallure.nl/ and http://ny.scsterallure.nl/index.mobile.html (this would be the player 2, mobile control)

Also I registered my routes in the global.asax start and that works (because otherwise my site wouldn't work locally)
The code I use not very complex, just a subclass of Hub with some methods.

**update** Seems that if tested in IE9 the server page does seem to work as it should, slow but it works. The transport method seems to be foreverframe.

Comment: I'm getting some similar behavior - but I'm in as much need of help as you are apparently :-). http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14065115/signalr-500-errors-during-ping-on-azure-website

Comment: Thanks, I just spend a few hours to convert my server app to NodeJs Socket.IO; works like a charm. Seems to me that SignalR isn't ready to be used. It  looks great but when it comes to be used in a versatile production environment it just doesn't cut it.

Comment: By the way, it turns out that my problem was my own fault - I was mixing a newer version of the client with the NuGet version of the server DLLs.