# SignalR 500 errors during "ping" on Azure website

Tags: azure, signalr, azure-web-app-service

I've got an ASP.NET 4.5 web app using SignalR 1.0.0-rc1 which I've pushed out to an Azure website for some quick-and-dirty testing (I'm mostly interested in this page here: http://alantaappbeta.azurewebsites.net/api/v3.0/Tests/Sample.htm).

The problem is that the page doesn't seem to want to talk to the SignalR service. The hubs and everything are registered correctly, as http://alantaappbeta.azurewebsites.net/signalr/hubs returns the correct client-side hubs file, and the call to /signalr/negotiate returns some  reasonable looking JSON.

```
{
  "Url":"/signalr",
  "ConnectionId":"a15023f9-c675-4fc2-9fd6-403a297f10c0",
  "KeepAlive":15.0,
  "DisconnectTimeout":40.0,
  "TryWebSockets":false,
  "WebSocketServerUrl":null,
  "ProtocolVersion":"1.1"
}
```

But when it calls /signalr/ping, it returns a 500 error, with the message "Protocol error: Unknown transport". The stack trace returned in the error page looks like this:

```
[InvalidOperationException]: Protocol error: Unknown transport.
at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.PersistentConnection.ProcessRequestAsync(HostContext context)
at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Hubs.HubDispatcher.ProcessRequestAsync(HostContext context)
at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Owin.CallHandler.Invoke(IDictionary`2 environment)
at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Owin.Handlers.HubDispatcherHandler.Invoke(IDictionary`2 environment)
at Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.OwinCallContext.Execute()
at Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.OwinHttpHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContextBase httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object extraData)
at Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.OwinHttpHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb, Object extraData)
at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

Because this is on Azure, I don't have access to all the troubleshooting tools you'd normally have, but what logs I have been able to get access to don't give me any information beyond the above.

I suppose it goes without saying that this runs fine on my local IIS instance :-).

Any suggestions?

Edit: This is how I'm opening my connection:

```
$.connection.hub.start({
    transport: 'auto',
    xdomain: true
}).done(function () {
    console.log('Connected with hub.id=' + $.connection.hub.id);
}).fail(function (e) {
    console.log('Unable to connect to SignalR Hubs: ' + e);
});
```

But neither the `.done()` nor the `.fail()` handlers are being called.

Oddly enough, if I set the transport to 'longPolling', I can get it to fail in a similar manner using IIS Express on my local box. But it doesn't seem to make any difference what I set the transport to on Azure: I still get the same error.

Comment: Are you using the dev branch?

Comment: Nope, just the RC1 package off of NuGet.

Comment: The ping endpoint isn't in the RC1 release.

Comment: Sorry, not sure I understand. Why is my client making the call then? And why is it only doing it on Azure? And (I should have mentioned this) why are neither the .done() nor the .fail() handlers for $.connection.hub.start() being called?

Comment: Never mind, figured it out. I was using the RC1 bits on the server, but was still somehow referencing the `dev` branch version of the `jquery.signalr.js` file. Once I got that straightened out, it all worked. Thanks for the pointer, and sorry for the trouble.

Comment: @KenSmith you should answer your own question, or close it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the issue was that I had a mix of different versions of SignalR on my machine: I was using the server-side DLLs from the NuGet package (1.0.0-rc1), but the JavaScript client file was from the `dev` branch. Once I got them all synchronized, everything worked. I'm still not sure precisely why the issue only showed up with Azure, but I suspect it has something to do with the precise transports supported by the different versions of IIS.